# How to fix element not allowed as child?

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to do a project for school and cannot figure out the error that says "element fig not allowed as child of body"

I have tried making the fig a child of the `<a>` but that didn't work. I'm truly stumped.

```
<body>
 <h1>&#128038;Gallery</h1>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
   <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
 </ul>
 <h2>Recent Photos</h2>
 <p>Our members are very active and love to share. Here are three recent sightings by club members. Click a thumbnail to see a larger view.</p>
 <fig>
 <a href="images/bluebird.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/bluebird-sm.jpg" alt="Bluebird"></a>
  <figcaption>Bluebird, by Stephan Swallow</figcaption></fig>
 <fig>
 <a href="images/canary.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/canary-sm.jpg" alt="Canary"></a>
  <figcaption>Canary, by Cheryl Raven</figcaption>
 </fig>
 <fig>
 <a href="images/robin.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/robin-sm.jpg" alt="Robin"></a>
  <figcaption>Robin, by Sandy Byrd</figcaption>
 </fig>
 <p><small>All content &copy; HAWC</small></p>
```

Comment: `<fig>` has been replaced by `<figure>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `<figure>` HTML tag instead of `<fig>`. You can read through [the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure).